# window.open from a window opened with window.open

Tags: javascript, window.open

i am trying to open a new window with window.open from a child window opened with window.open. But the first child closes on second window.open

Comment: Can you show us your code?

Answer (score 0):

This is down to the browser preventing what they deem to be bad user experience, and potentially infinite recursion. Check the first window opened with `window.open` — somewhere, you will probably find a notice that a "Popup window has been blocked" or something similar.

For example, if you were to have the following script in your page:

```
window.open(location)
```

…without the browser intervening and preventing the second execution of the code, you would trigger an infinite loop: the window opens a copy of itself, which opens a copy of itself, *ad infinitum*.

To avoid this, try to limit your site or application's user experience to one or 2 windows. If the windows are assigned names, and operate in the same domain, they can change each-others locations. This may fulfill your needs — but if it doesn't, you're stuck!

Answer (score 0):

With no code available I'm guessing but, you're not using the window.open method like so are you:

```
window.open(URL,name);
```

If you're specifying the same name in both window.open calls then the window being opened will replace the existing window with the same name which would give the behaviour your described.